# DataGridView Only Displaying Headers

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a WinForms application and I am trying to get a DataGridView to populate at runtime. Under the initializeComponent code of the form I have:

```
 _BackEndDataSet DS = new _BackEndDataSet();
 DataView theDataView = new DataView(DS.Tables["CLIENTS"]);
 dataGridViewClients.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 dataGridViewClients.DataSource = theDataView;
```

Where _BackEndDataSet is dataset and CLIENTS is the table I would like to see.

The columns for the table show up but no data.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you populate DataSet?

Comment: With an Access accdb file which resides within the project.

Comment: if `ataGridViewClients.AutoGenerateColumns = true` and columns showed then I assume your DataTable is empty